# problem with installation of gradlew

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am trying to install gradlew through this command with the help of [http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html]

I got this error "package motion_planning_msgs does not exist"

does anyone have any idea how should I solve this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46841/problem-with-installation-of-gradlew/) by [iran](https://answers.ros.org/users/3476/iran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Iran,

I guess you are using ROS Fuerte, right? The package that was called `motion_planning_msgs` in Electric has been merged into `arm_navigation_msgs` in Fuerte, so it doesn't exist any more. My guess is that you still have some artifacts from an Electric build lying around somewhere. Can you delete the directories `~/.m2` and `~/.ros/rosjava/` and try again?

If that doesn't help, check that your environment variables are set up correctly. In particular, check that the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is correct (see "Environment setup" in the [ROS installation instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu)).

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

should say something like this (first some place(s) under your home dir where you put your own packages, then `/opt/ros/fuerte` stuff, no electric):

```
/home/martin/ros-fuerte:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
```

---

**UPDATE (solution):** For later reference: In private communication with Iran, it turned out that the problem's cause was that an older revision of `rosjava_core` was built with electric, then `rosjava_core` was updated to the current tip and compiled with Fuerte. Removing the `rosjava_core` directory and cloning it fresh solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iran](https://answers.ros.org/users/3476/iran/) on 2012-10-28**:
Yes, I have ROS electric installed in my computer. but, as you suggested, I delete ~/.m2 and ~/.ros/rosjava/ and then I try ./gradlew install. Again I have the same error. Also,  my environment variable setup which was correct. any other suggestion? what about deleting the whole ROS electric?